# drupal site doesn't work without index.php?q=user

Tags: drupal, configuration, drupal-6

I have a Drupal 6 site. it has clean URL enabled. when I edit a profile it says page not found. but on the link when I add index.php?q=user, it works. but if that is not there I get an error.

after Google search I came to no its something about, clean URL, and apache config. but I cant seem to no what to do from here.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed and configured mod_rewrite module for apache server ? If not then you definitely need to do that first and then clear cache and see the magic.

Go to the link below and try configuring your apache. If you still have problems, please be more specific about the operating system your server is running on and the steps taken by you so far, so that one can guide you directly to those steps.

https://drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls

Comment: iv looked at that, but cant find how to configure mod_rewrite. which file do i change

Comment: ?? am not sure what the problem is, where can i configure my apache?